# Create NPM Package with dependencies just for examples

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, npm-install

I'm working on an NPM package right now.

The main code for the package (repo/src/maincode.js) has a few dev dependencies and a few dependencies needed to run it. When the user installs the npm package (through npm i) these dependencies will need be installed.

Now, that being said, I also want to create a react project that showcases this npm package, and have it live in the same repo, in an examples directory (repo/examples/react/app.js). This react app may have its own dependencies and dev dependencies, but I really don't want all of these to be forced onto the user when they're installing my npm package just to use in their projects.

How might I go about solving this problem? Is there a way to create a set of dependencies that are only installed if you are running a particular script, or running example code ?

Answer (score 2):

You can give the `examples` directory its own `package.json` file and instruct folks who want to run the examples to `cd` into the `examples` directory and run `npm i` there. Any code in the `examples` directory that imports a module will look in its own `node_modules` before checking the `node_modules` in the parent directory.

The [MarkoJS examples repository](https://github.com/marko-js/examples) takes this approach and even makes it more granular. Instead of having a single `package.json` for the `examples` directory, there is a `package.json` for each separate example.

If you want, you can create a helper script in the main `package.json` for the user [so they can do something like `npm run build-examples` and it will do the `npm install` for them](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-run-script) as part of the process.